# How to have both Greek Alphabet and LaTeX command of it in the same table in exported PDF (TEX)?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-table

Just want to create a table of LaTeX command for Greek Alphabet. One column for the Greek Alphabet and one for the command.

When I use `\beta`, it shows as Greek alphabet in the exported PDF file. How could I escape it to make it shows as LaTeX command?

Comment: Is this an Emacs question?  Sounds like you are looking for how to escape `\beta` in LaTeX.

Comment: In org, you could show it as verbatim, if you wrote it like `=\beta=` or `~\beta~`.